pytest + moto でのLambda呼出（invoke)
初めての質問失礼いたします。
今現在、pytestとmotoを利用してLambdaの単体テスト実行を行いたいと思っております。
環境



項目
情報




言語
python(3.11)


OS
Windows11


moto
ver 5.0.16


pytest
ver 8.3.3



テスト対象のLambdaから別のLambdaを呼出す処理が存在するため、
motoを利用して疑似的にLambda作成を行い正常に呼ばれているかの簡単なテストを行うことで、Lambda→Lambdaのテストが可能かの確認を行いました。
なお、今回はDockerの利用は想定しておりません。
結果としてはLambda呼び出しは出来たものの、期待していた戻り値が返ってこず、問題の原因またはこれ自体が仕様通りなのかが不明のため困っております。
以下が実証に用いたコードです。
conftest.py
import boto3
import pytest
import json
import os
from moto import mock_aws
import zipfile
import io

REGION = 'ap-northeast-1'
PYTHON_VERSION = 'python3.11'

@pytest.fixture
def aws_credentials():
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = REGION

@pytest.fixture
def init_lambda(aws_credentials):
    with mock_aws(config={'lambda': {'use_docker': False}}):
        # ロール作成
        iam = boto3.client('iam', region_name=REGION)
        dummy_arn = iam.create_role(
            RoleName='dummy_role',
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument=json.dumps({
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }]
            }),
            Path='/dummy-path'
        )['Role']['Arn']
        
        # Lambda作成
        lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name=REGION)
        zip_content = get_test_zip_file1()

        lambda_client.create_function(
            FunctionName='Hoge',
            Runtime='python3.8',
            Role=dummy_arn,
            Handler="lambda_function.lambda_handler",
            Code={"ZipFile": zip_content},
        )
        
        yield lambda_client  # lambda_clientを返す


def get_test_zip_file1():
    pfunc = """
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("custom log event")
    if "error" in event:
        raise Exception('I failed!')
    return {'StatusCode': 200, 'message': 'OK'}
"""
    return _process_lambda(pfunc)

def _process_lambda(func_str):
    zip_output = io.BytesIO()
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_output, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zip_file.writestr("lambda_function.py", func_str)
    zip_file.close()
    zip_output.seek(0)
    return zip_output.read()

test.py
import boto3
import json

def test_invoke_lambda_01(init_lambda):
    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

    # Lambda関数を呼び出し
    payload = {
        'Hoge': 'hoge'
    }
    
    resp = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='Hoge',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(payload)
    )
    
    # レスポンスを取得
    response_payload = json.loads(resp['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8'))
    print(response_payload)
    # 戻り値を確認
    assert response_payload['StatusCode'] == 200
    assert response_payload['message'] == 'OK'


上記を実行した場合、期待していた戻り値ではなく、Lambda呼び出し時に設定したペイロードがそのまま返ってきてしまいます。
コンソール出力
test.py::test_invoke_lambda_01 {'Hoge': 'hoge'}
FAILED test.py::test_invoke_lambda_01 - KeyError: 'StatusCode'

上記に関しまして、解決策をご教授頂きたいです。
ご支援のほどよろしくお願いいたします。
